# MVC 3 jquery ajax post 2 objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a controller action that takes two objects as arguments. I can't get it to work at all they always come back as null. My latest try looks like below. I have tried many other variations. In this case the FormInfo class is a class with 2 properties that are types for Form1 and Form2. I have also tried having the controller take in the two classes as arguments and the data part looked like { form1: form1Data, form2: form2Data } that was not working as well. I also tried using JSON.stringify to form the data with no luck.
Looking in the network monitor I see the data going back to the server it's just the engine that MVC uses to decode the query string to the objects can't handle what I'm passing back.
Thanks in advance for any information!

**ClientSide**

```
var formData = $("#form1").serialize();
var formData2 = $("#form2").serialize();
var formInfo = new Object();

formInfo.FormData = formData;
formInfo.FormData2 = formData2;

$.ajax({
    url: 'Controller/Action',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  formInfo,
    success: function (data) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

**ServerSide**

```
public ActionResult SaveForms(FormInfo formInfo)
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

Comment: try with `JSON.stringify(formInfo)`

Comment: What does the post content look like?  Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I tried that no dice :(

Comment: @Maess I can do that but it will take me a while to scrub the data for stackoverflow. I think that's on the right track though something is happening where the MVC engine doesn't know whats what.

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper can you post the class defination of `FormInfo`

Comment: FormInfo is a class which that looks like 
public class FormInfo
{
    public FormData { get; set; }
    public FormData2 { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the a JSON request in conjunction with the [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) jQuery method. Let's suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class FormInfo
{
    public Form1Data Form1Data { get; set; }
    public Form2Data Form2Data { get; set; }
}
```

where `Form1Data` and `Form2Data` are some completely arbitrary complex classes. Now on the client we suppose that you have 2 distinct forms (`#form1` and `#form2` whose input element names match your complex structures in terms of [default model binder wire format](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)). Sending an AJAX request and packing the 2 forms together becomes trivial:

```
var form1Data = {};
$.each($('#form1').serializeArray(), function () {
    form1Data[this.name] = this.value;
});

var form2Data = {};
$.each($('#form2').serializeArray(), function () {
    form2Data[this.name] = this.value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller")',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        form1Data: form1Data,
        form2Data: form2Data
    }),
    success: function (result) {
        // TODO: do something with the result 
    }
});
```

And of course the controller action you are POSTing to looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(FormInfo formInfo)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: As always thanks Darin!
Didn't work for me but I think I'm doing something wrong with the serialization, well obviously I am :). I'm going to toy with it some more later today after I get some productive work done :) I'll mark as answered as soon as I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like this but i have a object and other Formdata to pass my Controller

var discrepancy = self.newCptyReply();

```
        if ($('#UploadFile')[0]) {
            var upload = new FormData(),
                file = $('#UploadFile')[0].files[0];

            upload.append('id', self.globalMessageId());
            upload.append('discrepancy', ko.toJSON(discrepancy));
            upload.append('doc', file); 


        }           

        datacontext.saveCptyToReply(self, upload);
```

And in controller signature

```
   public ActionResult SaveCptyToReply(Guid id, Trade discrepancy, HttpPostedFileBase doc)
```

But when it reaches Controller id , doc are ok but discrepancy is null... It has data when funciton is called..

What to do...